# Cannot store drag and drop items in localStorage in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hello I am writing a simple aplication to asign tas to the user by using drag and drop option.
(By using angular-dragdrop.min.js file).
I can keep data in local storage but after refresh $$hashKey
automatically changed so even if array is in local storage of the browser so You cannot see item inside user box.

[Link to github project](https://github.com/Jaszui/JaszuiTaskManagement)

```
var App = angular.module('drag-and-drop', ['ngDragDrop']);
```

App.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope) {

```
$scope.list1 = [];
$scope.list2 = [];
$scope.list3 = [];

$scope.list5 = [
    { 'title': 'Item 1', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 2', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 3', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 4', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 5', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 6', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 7', 'drag': true },
    { 'title': 'Item 8', 'drag': true }

];

var mainList = $scope.list5;
var firstList = $scope.list1;
var secondList = $scope.list2;
var thirdList = $scope.list3;
```

$scope.doSomething = function () {

```
    localStorage.setItem('mainList', JSON.stringify(mainList));
    localStorage.setItem('firstList', JSON.stringify(firstList));
    localStorage.setItem('secondList', JSON.stringify(secondList));
    localStorage.setItem('thirdList', JSON.stringify(thirdList));
    console.log(mainList);
    console.log(firstList);
    console.log(secondList);
    console.log(thirdList);

};
if(localStorage.getItem('mainList')){
    $scope.list5.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mainList')));
    console.log(mainList);
}
if(localStorage.getItem('firstList')){
    $scope.list1.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('firstList')));
    console.log(firstList);
}
if(localStorage.getItem('secondList')){
    $scope.list2.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('secondList')));
    console.log(secondList);
}
if(localStorage.getItem('thirdList')){
    $scope.list3.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('thirdList')));
    console.log(thirdList);
}
```

And part of index.html

```
<div class="main-content col-md-12 col-lg-12" ng-controller="oneCtrl">
            <div class="btn btn-droppable" ng-repeat="item in list5" data-drop="true" ng-model='list5'
                 data-jqyoui-options="{accept:'.btn-draggable:not([ng-model=list5])'}"
                 jqyoui-droppable="{index: {{$index}}}">
                <div class="btn btn-info btn-draggable" data-drag="{{item.drag}}"
                     data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="list5"
                     jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},placeholder:true,animate:true}" ng-hide="!item.title">
                    {{item.title}}
                </div>
            </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" ng-model='list2' data-jqyoui-options="optionsList2"
                             jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <div class="btn btn-info btn-draggable" ng-repeat="item in list2"
                                     ng-show="item.title" data-drag="{{item.drag}}"
                                     data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="list2"
                                     jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true}">{{item.title}}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

Comment: You should parse the item getting from local storage: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mainList'));`

Comment: You mean I should modify this part?if(localStorage.getItem('secondList')){
    $scope.list2.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('secondList')));
    console.log(secondList);

Comment: This part: `if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mainList'))` and the similar `if` statements, where you're getting items from local storage. And check, does you `if` statements fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with JSON.parse and JSON.stringy.

You should use angular.toJson and angular.fromJson instead as it will strip out the $$hashKey
Example:

```
 //equals to JSON.stringify
 localStorage.setItem('mainList', angular.toJson(mainList));

 //equals to JSON.parse
 if(localStorage.getItem('mainList')){
    $scope.list5.push(angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('mainList')));
    console.log(mainList);
 }
```

**UPDATE**

This is wrong, you are pushing array into an array so you are create an array of array. Whereas you want an array of objects.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('firstList')){
    //This is what you are doing, this is wrong as this will create 
    // array of array
    $scope.list1.push(angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('secondList')));
}
```

What you should be doing is this

```
if(localStorage.getItem('firstList')){
        //this will assign the array stored in ls to the list1 var
        $scope.list1 = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('firstList'));
        console.log(firstList);
    }
```

Comment: when i try to implement this code inline `    $scope.doSomething = function () {


        localStorage.setItem('mainList', angular.fromJson(mainList));
        localStorage.setItem('firstList', angular.fromJson(firstList));
        localStorage.setItem('secondList', angular.fromJson(secondList));
        localStorage.setItem('thirdList', angular.fromJson(thirdList));}` i get an error Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Your data ("mainList") is already an object. No need to parse it.

Comment: Now console show me  (2) ["[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[o…],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]", "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[o…],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"]
app.js:71 ["[object Object]"]
app.js:76 ["[object Object]"]

Comment: You have to do the opposite of what you are doing right now.  $scope.doSomething = function () { localStorage.setItem('mainList', angular.toJson(mainList)); localStorage.setItem('firstList', angular.toJson(firstList)); localStorage.setItem('secondList', angular.toJson(secondList)); localStorage.setItem('thirdList', angular.toJson(thirdList));} , This is what you have to do when you set item.

Comment: Console show me difference format now but when I refresh a page I still cannot see my items inside.However I can't place a new one before clear storage

Comment: I add those changes to my git

Comment: if(localStorage.getItem('mainList')){
        // $scope.list5.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mainList')));
        $scope.list1.push(localStorage.getItem('mainList'));
        console.log(mainList);
    } Change this to 
    if(localStorage.getItem('mainList')){
        // $scope.list5.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mainList')));
        $scope.list1.push(angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('mainList')));
        console.log(mainList);
    } for all lists

Comment: Okay, I see what you are doing wrong here. I am updating my answer.

Comment: @jasuri did it work? Don't forget to upvote if it did :)

Comment: Now it works :D Thank you very much I really appreciate your help and  your time